# How to store variables values in a class i.e "settings"?

Tags: java, javafx

OK. After spending literally a few hours trying to get things working I give up.

Basically I am creating a program in which user inputs some values, then after hitting button a new scene is created and depending on the values it was given, different things take place.
My problem - I created "Settings.class" with a few variables with getters and setters. My assumption was to store the values input in there and whenever needed I have easy access to them using getters.
For some reason it doesn't work.

Keep in mind I simplified it as much as I can because It'd look very messy and would be very long if I pasted my original code. I made sure that the core of the problem is the same.

Settings class:

```
public class Settings {    
private boolean diamonds;  

public boolean getDiamonds() {
    return diamonds;
}
public void setDiamonds(boolean diamonds) {
    this.diamonds = diamonds;
}
}
```

Controller class:

```
public class Controller implements Initializable {
private Settings settings = new Settings();
private ProblematicOne prob = new ProblematicOne();

public void handleGoAction() throws IOException {

settings.setDiamonds(true);    

prob.editText("This shall be set");

/* ..creating new stage and scene here no reason to paste it here, no probs with that.. */

@Override
public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {        
}
}
}
```

And crème de la crème, problematic class:

```
public class ProblematicOne{

private Setting settings = new Settings();
String toBeEdited = "";  // 

public void editText(String text){

if(settings.getDiamonds){      // for some reason it doesn't work; The getter returns false.
    toBeEdited = text;
}else if(!settings.getDiamonds){
    toBeEdited = "getDiamonds is false";
}
}
}
```

Comment: You have to share the instance of Setting . Right now, you have 2 different instances of Setting, each with their own value of diamonds.

Comment: Well, probably several instances of `Settings`, as you create a new one every time you create a new controller, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your issue is that ProblematicClass creates a new instance of settings, so the value is not accessible. You need to pass the same instance into the other class, or make your variables in settings class static, so you can access them without instance:

```
public class Settings {    
    private static boolean diamonds;  

    public static boolean getDiamonds() {
        return diamonds;
    }
    public static void setDiamonds(boolean diamonds) {
        this.diamonds = diamonds;
    }
}
```

And use it without instance:

```
Settings.setDiamonds(true);
Settings.getDiamonds();
```

Comment: Note that if you do this, you commit yourself to only ever having one set of "settings properties" in the entire application, always. So if you ever wanted to open a new "view" with different settings (say in a new window or tab), you would have to rewrite huge portions of the application to do this. The solutions using singletons suffer from the same problem. A dependency-injection approach may well be more robust and maintainable.

Answer (score 1):

Alright, first off, what you are trying to do can be achieved by serializing the object (i.e Settings) and storing it. Or, simpler, just write to a file with values and load from there when you want to instantiate the class.

Look at this line in your "ProblematicOne"
`private Setting settings = new Settings();`

You just created a new instance of Settings. This instance does not have any idea of your Settings instance in your Controller.

Another way is to make your Settings class a singleton and then just reuse it. Example:

Settings.java

```
public class Settings {  

    private static Settings instance = null;

    private boolean diamonds;  

    public boolean getDiamonds() {
        return diamonds;
    }

    public void setDiamonds(boolean diamonds) {
        this.diamonds = diamonds;
    }

    private Settings() {}

    public static Settings getInstance(){
        return instance == null ? new Settings() : instance;
    }
}
```

Then in your Controller class just get the instance using the `getInstance()` method;

`private Settings settings = Settings.getInstance();`

Similarly, when you use it again in your ProblematicOne class, use the `getInstance()` method

Answer (score 0):

in the following class with out setting value to settings object, you are trying to use get, which will return default value.

```
public class ProblematicOne{

private Setting settings = new Settings();
String toBeEdited = "";  // 

public void editText(String text){

if(settings.getDiamonds){      // for some reason it doesn't work; The getter returns false.
    toBeEdited = text;
}else if(!settings.getDiamonds){
    toBeEdited = "getDiamonds is false";
}
}
}
```

if you want to use the settings object which you created in the controller then pass settings object to editText method in the ProblematicOne class.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are instantiating Setting class twice. You set the

```
    settings.setDiamonds(true); //in one instance
```

and you expect to retrive this value in second instance in class ProblematicOne.
Try to solve this by instantiating Settings only once in Controller class and pass the same to ProblematicOne. Frame your code such that you instantiate

```
    private Setting settings = new Settings();
```

only once in your whole application. Consider making this class singleton. Read about singleton instantiation here
http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html